# Parametrization of a Curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I am working through my script of Algebraic Geometry and have some questions to Parametrization:

1. What is the exact definition of Parametrization? 
   We wrote in our script: $k \to C$ with $t\mapsto (\varphi(t),\psi(t))$ where $\varphi(t),\psi(t)\in k(t)=Quot(k[t])$.
   Is this the formal definition? The parametrization is the map of $k$ to a curve $C$?
2. How do I do the Parametrization? We did some examples, but I am not sure how we 'saw' how to do it:

   - $C = V(y^2-x^3-x^2)$. Say $y = x*t$. So $t^2*x^2-x^3-x^2 = x^2(t^2-x-1)$.
     So $x = t^2 -1$ and $y = t^3 - 3$. 
     Therefore $k\to C$ by $t\mapsto (t^2-1,t^3-t)$ and  $-1,1 \mapsto (0,0)$
   - $C = V(x^2+y^2-17)$. $P = (1,4)\in C$. Say $y = t(x-1)+4$. 
     ... $x = \frac{t^2-8t-1}{1+t^2}$ and $y = \frac{-8t^2-2t}{1+t^2}+4$

     How do I see here that  I have to choose first $y = x*t$, and then $y = t(x-1)+4$?
     Is it maybe that I look for a point $P = (a,b)\in C$ (with $C$ my curve), and then choose $y = t*(x-a)+b$?

It would also be nice if someone knows a good paper or book explaining parametrization!

Thanks and Best! Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the parametrization is the rational map. As a remark, the parametrization may not be surjective, but it must be *almost surjective*, that is, almost all the points of the curve must be contained in the image of the parametrization. More formally, we ask the parametrization to be dominant, that is, that the image must be a dense subset of the curve (wrt Zariski topology), or if you prefer, the closure of the image must be the curve.

As an example, we can parametrize the circle as follows:
$$ t \mapsto ( 2t/(t^2+1), (t^2-1)/(t^2+1) ) $$

Note that the point (0,1) is not in the image, but the others are.

If you want a good source, I recommend you the excellent book *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*, by D. Cox, J. Little and D. O'Shea. In particular, section 3 of chapter 1 (p. 14). The exercises of the section may be also helpful in order to develope a good technique and a geometric intuition for parametrizing varieties (in particular curves).

Comment: Thank you! I just started to skim through the first chapter and it looks really helpful and well explaines :)